# QWebEngineView request body interception

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview

A user using QWebEngineView in my application fills some form. This form uses post method to submit data to server. How can I get params from user's body request?

I've found such thing as [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html), but it works only for urls.

Comment: some code examples are always helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest).

Whenever a form is submitted, you can get the contents of input by using JavaScript and then accept the request to proceed as usual.

Comment: Nice. And what abot implementetion? Do I need to create my custom webpage from QWebEnginePage and overload acceptNavigationRequest(), and also create a custom webview and reimplement page() method?

Comment: @DenisPopov just implement webpage with acceptNavigationRequest and set the page to your QWebEngineView (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setPage).

Answer (score 1):

Like [Anmol Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7526789/anmol-gautam) said, you need to reimplement [QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) function and get needed data using JavaScript.

Here is an example how to do it:

**mywebpage.h**

```
#include <QWebEnginePage>

class MyWebPage : public QWebEnginePage
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWebPage(QWebEngineProfile *profile = Q_NULLPTR, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

protected:
    bool acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl & url, QWebEnginePage::NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame);
}
```

**mywebpage.cpp**

```
MyWebPage::MyWebPage(QWebEngineProfile *profile, QObject *parent):QWebEnginePage(profile, parent),
{
//...
}

bool MyWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl & url, QWebEnginePage::NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame)
{
    if(type == QWebEnginePage::NavigationTypeFormSubmitted)
    {
        qDebug() << "[FORMS] Submitted" <<  url.toString();
        QString jsform = "function getformsvals()"
                         "{var result;"
                          "for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){"
                         "for(var x = 0; x < document.forms[i].length; x++){"
                         "result += document.forms[i].elements[x].name + \" = \" +document.forms[i].elements[x].value;"
                         "}}"
                         "return result;} getformsvals();";

        this->runJavaScript(jsform, [](const QVariant &result){ qDebug() << "[FORMS] found: " << result; });
    }
    return true;
}
```

use [QWebEngineView::setPage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setPage) to set your WebPage subclass to WebView before you call WebViews load function.

Here is a link for more info about [HTML DOM forms Collection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp)